# Use CSV data in table caption?

Tags: captions, import, csv, csvsimple

I want to use some data, imported with csvsimple, in a table caption.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
column1,column2,column3
name1,val1a,val1b
name2,val2a,val2b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\csvget}[3]{\csvreader[no head, filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{#2}]{#1}{}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}
   \centering
   My Tabular
   \caption{A caption \csvget{data.csv}{2}{\csvcolii}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Using the code from above I get an error like `Argument of \@caption has an extra...`
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
CX

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with fragile commands. See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

With e-tex compatible compiler you may use `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
column1,column2,column3
name1,val1a,val1b
name2,val2a,val2b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\csvget}[3]{\csvreader[no head, filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{#2}]{#1}{}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \csvautotabular{data.csv}
   \caption{A caption \csvget{data.csv}{2}{\protect\csvcolii}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Without it you may use `\DeclareRobustCommand`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
column1,column2,column3
name1,val1a,val1b
name2,val2a,val2b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\csvget}[3]{\csvreader[no head, filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{#2}]{#1}{}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \csvautotabular{data.csv}
   \caption{A caption \csvget{data.csv}{2}{\protect\csvcolii}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the result is:

[image: result]

Comment: Using your code-expamples I get strange results in the list of tables. any improvements?

Comment: @cxkoda I think I just found out what you mean with "strange results" You mean the text in the list of tables is different to the caption. I think I got a solution. Please test after I updated my solution.

Comment: I think, someone else might provide a better solution...

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Your answer solves the question in my humble opinion. There are no "strange results" anymore ...

Comment: Good to hear that it is working. I had updated the answer (see under the answer at the field "edited date", also I said that I'll update the in a comment above)

Answer (score 1):

*edit (2017): the code was broken since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` as from then on package `xint` does not load `xinttools`. Thus rather than `\usepackage{xint}`, one needed here `\usepackage{xinttools}`.*

Here is some general purpose csv-file handling macro `\ReadCSVfile {filename}\to \MACRO`. Then `\MACRO {i}{j}` expands to the `j`th item of the `i`th row and you can do all you want in `\caption`'s or whatever. The filename must be given with its extension.

> [image: csvcaption]

Code relies on the macros of [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) which have been very recently been moved to the `xinttools` package. But there is still at least one dependency of `xinttools` on `xint` due to some oversight, so we load `xint` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
column1,column2,column3
name1,val1a,val1b
name2,val2a,val2b
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xinttools}

% VERY SIMPLE CSV HANDLING. Syntax:

% \ReadCSVfile {data.csv} \to \DATA

% \DATA WILL BE DEFINED AS A TWO ARGUMENTS COMMAND:

% \DATA {0}{0}: number of lines
% \DATA {i}{0}: number of items in i th line
% \DATA {i}{j}: j th item of i th line
% \DATA {0}{i}: the ith line as a list of braced items.

% WARNING: \DATA (or whatever it is called) WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.

\makeatletter
% example \ReadCSVfile {data.csv} \to \DATA
% WARNING: macro \DATA gets defined with no check if it already exists !!
\newcount\ReadCSV@linecount
\newcount\ReadCSV@itemcount
\newcommand\ReadCSVfile [3]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}
    {%
      \edef\ReadCSV@restore{\endlinechar=\the\endlinechar\relax
                            \catcode`\noexpand\@=\the\catcode`\@\relax}%
      \endlinechar=-1 
      \makeatletter % in case csv file contains LaTeX macros with @ character
      \newread\ReadCSV@instream
      \openin\ReadCSV@instream\@filef@und
      \ReadCSV@linecount\z@
      \xintloop
         \read\ReadCSV@instream to\ReadCSV@oneline
      \unless\ifeof\ReadCSV@instream
         \advance\ReadCSV@linecount\@ne
         \ReadCSV@itemcount\z@
% we suppress all spaces around commas from the input file. Use braces around
% the item with spaces to force such spaces.
%
% the reason for such definition is for optimization in order for the conversion
% from  CSV format to be done only once. We take care not to expand the file
% contents, in case they have some LaTeX meaning.        
% 
         \toks@ \expandafter{\romannumeral0\expandafter\xintcsvtolist
                     \expandafter{\expandafter\space\ReadCSV@oneline}}%
         \expandafter
         \edef\csname CSV@\string#3@0.\the\ReadCSV@linecount\endcsname
                            {\the\toks@}%
         \xintFor* ####1 in {\the\toks@} \do
         {%
           \advance\ReadCSV@itemcount\@ne
           \expandafter
           \def\csname CSV@\string#3@\the\ReadCSV@linecount.%
                                     \the\ReadCSV@itemcount\endcsname
                  {####1}%
         }%
         \expandafter
         \def\csname CSV@\string#3@\the\ReadCSV@linecount.%
                                      0\expandafter\endcsname
                                       \expandafter{\the\ReadCSV@itemcount}%
      \repeat
      \closein\ReadCSV@instream
      \ReadCSV@restore
      \expandafter
      \edef\csname CSV@\string#3@0.0\endcsname {\the\ReadCSV@linecount}%
      \def#3####1####2%
      {\csname CSV@\string#3@\the\numexpr####1.\the\numexpr####2\endcsname }%
    }
    {\typeout{No file #1}}%
}


\ReadCSVfile {data.csv} \to \DATA

% \DATA {0}{0}: number of lines
% \DATA {i}{0}: number of items in i th line
% \DATA {i}{j}: j th item of i th line
% \DATA {0}{i}: the ith line as a list of *braced* items.

% spaces around commas in input file are REMOVED.


\begin{document}
\listoftables
\bigskip

\begin{table}
   \centering
   My Tabular
   \caption{Second of second line \DATA {2}{2}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
   \centering
   My Tabular
   \caption{Third of first line \DATA {1}{3}}
\end{table}

The data file contains \DATA {0}{0} lines. 

\newcounter{linecount}
\setcounter{linecount}{0}

% Note: we must use \endgraf because \xintloop currently does not accept \par.
\xintloop
\stepcounter{linecount}
The line numbered \arabic{linecount} contains \DATA {\value{linecount}}{0}
entries. Here they are:%
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\DATA {\value{linecount}}{0}}} 
\do 
  { \DATA {\value{linecount}}{#1},} and that's
  it for that line.\endgraf
\ifnum\value{linecount}<\DATA{0}{0}
\repeat

\bigskip

We can also handle files with lines of different lengths.

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
column1,column2,column3,column4
name1,val1a,val1b
name2,val2a,val2b,X,Y,Z
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
\end{filecontents*}

\ReadCSVfile {data2.csv} \to \DATAII

\setcounter{linecount}{0}

% Note: we must use \endgraf because \xintloop currently does not accept \par.
\xintloop
\stepcounter{linecount}
The line numbered \arabic{linecount} contains \DATAII {\value{linecount}}{0}
entries. Here they are: 
\xintListWithSep{, }{\DATAII {0}{\value{linecount}}}.\endgraf 
\ifnum\value{linecount}<\DATAII {0}{0}
\repeat

\setcounter{linecount}{0}

Here is a nice Plain \TeX{} alignment with this data:

\tabskip1em
\fbox{\vbox{\halign{&\hfil#\hfil\cr
        \xintloop 
        \ifnum\value{linecount}<\DATAII {0}{0}
        \stepcounter{linecount}%
        \xintListWithSep {&}{\DATAII {0}{\value{linecount}}}%
        \cr 
        \repeat
}}}

\medskip \LaTeX{}'s tabulars can be used with lines
having a varying number of items but one must know the maximal number of items
from all rows (I think).

\end{document}
```